# STARTTLS extension not supported by server - Getting this error when trying to send an email through Django and a private email address

Tags: python, django, django-email

I registered a domain and a private email using namecheap.com. I am trying to send an email from this private email. However, I get the error in the title.

In my settings.py, I have these settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.privateemail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'contact@mysite.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

And I am trying to send the email through a view:

```
send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'contact@mysite.com',
    ['myname@gmail.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

However, I get this error:

```
SMTPException at /
STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
```

Any idea why? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT

After changing the EMAIL_USE_TLS to False, and also removing it to check both separately, I get this error now:

```
SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

Any idea why? Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

your server `mail.privateemail.com` does not know what is `STARTTLS` SMTP Commnad is

this may happen in two cases:

1. your server (mail.privateemail.com) do not support secure communication at all and you need to use plain, non-encrypted communication.
2. you are trying to connect to the port that is already using SSL as the communication, then STARTTLS to upgrade connection to secure make no sense whatsoever.
3. your server is configured improperly and ignores STARTTLS on submission port (587).

Judging, that you are connecting to port 587 which should provide plain communication - it's either 1 or 3.

If you want this just work, remove `EMAIL_USE_TLS = True` or set it to `False`, otherwise - SMTP server configuration should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, but this still does not work. Now, I get this error: **SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.**

Comment: This is totally different error, meaning that your SMTP server does not support authentication, remove/disable EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD options, an then rollup on the floor and cry for your smtp server as it is open for the spammers...

Comment: Wait what? So you are saying I can't send emails from the private email I just bought? T_T Is there any solution at all then?

Comment: who says not? just looks like everyone can :D

Comment: Any idea how though?

Comment: if you have open SMTP server - that does not require authentication... then everyone can send email through it

Comment: So should I just remove the EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD?

Comment: @Jerzyk 4 years later, I'm rolled up on the floor and laughing at your comment XD

Answer (score 2):

You may try SSL instead of TLS by making following changes in `settings.py`

```
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_PORT = 465
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Either setup TLS on your mail server or use `EMAIL_USE_TLS = False`.

Comment: Thanks, but this still does not work. Now, I get this error: **SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.**

Comment: Hi, TerenceLam, did you fix it? me too, always got those errors!!! Do you know the solution now? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue with modifying below line of code, by adding port number with server name:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.mycompany.com:587')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have solved the problem yet. I also recently try the 2-month free private email package from NameCheap. Here is my code and it works for me as of Jan 2018:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

fromaddr = 'account@yourdomain.com'
toaddrs  = "recipient@somedomain.com"
SMTPServer = 'mail.privateemail.com'
port = 465 #587
login = "account@yourdomain.com"
password = "password"

msg = EmailMessage()
msgtxt = "http://www.google.com"+"\n\n"+"This is a test."
msg.set_content(msgtxt)
msg['Subject'] = "Test message"
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddrs

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SMTPServer, port) #use smtplib.SMTP() if port is 587
#server.starttls()
server.login(login, password)
server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

Hope this help!

PS. You can also use port 587, but you have to use `smtplib.SMTP()` instead of `smtplib.SMTP_SSL()`, and also have to un-comment the `server.starttls()` line.