# How to send a mail using gmail in Django 1.10 on windows

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I have tried answers to other [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134714/starttls-extension-not-supported-by-server-getting-this-error-when-trying-to-s) but none of them tend to fix my error.
I am trying to make a simple django program which sends a mail when a specific button is clicked
 My settings include the following -

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

But while testing the following code in python shell.

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Body', to=['def@domain.com'])
email.send()
```

I got the following error message -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Nikhil Khandelwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smt
plib.py", line 751, in starttls
"STARTTLS extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
```

Please suggest ways to remove this error keeping in mind that I am beginner in django and python. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you search google for the error?

Comment: @Soviut  Yes I did but the answers I found couldnt fix my error and I got the same error every time.