# STARTTLS extension not supported by server in django

Tags: python, django, gmail

i am using gmail to do this, and i'm still at development. it just keeps throwing this error. yesterday it was working. sometimes it would also stop and show this error, but throughout today it haven't been working as expected

setting.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"

EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_HOST_USER = "testemail@gmail.com"

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "mypassword"
```

views.py

```
def mail_letter(request):
    emails = NewsLetter.objects.all()
    df = read_frame(emails, fieldnames=['email'])
    mail_list = df['email'].values.tolist()
    print(mail_list)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MailMessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            # Sending Messages
            title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
            message = form.cleaned_data.get('message')
            send_mail(
                title,
                message,
                '',
                mail_list,
                fail_silently=False,
            )
            # Success Alert
            messages.success(request, f"Messages sent successfully")
            subscribed = True
            return redirect('elements:mail_letter')
    else:
        form = MailMessageForm()
```

Comment: ***it just keep throwing this error*** - provide your error

Comment: @ankit-tiwari this is the error - STARTTLS extension not supported by server in django

Comment: check these https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905369/14457833 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/38138965/14457833

Comment: @ankit-tiwari  okay I've seen the question, there's a lot of answers can you please show me what to do, I exactly do not know what to do right now 

Comment: Hello @DestinyFranks I think you should try this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38138965/14457833

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was later fixed by connecting to a new network, my network connection was not good